# Format function output as a customised multiple lines string

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a function which gives output with simple format. 
If I already calculated estimated values of beta's, what should I do if I want following result format.

```
Coefficients  
-------------  
Constant: 5.2  
Beta1: 4  
Beta2: 9  
Beta3: 2  
.
.
.
```

I tried `cat()` function but to use `cat()`, I have to write every line manually like:

```
cat("Coefficients","\n","-------------","\n","Constant: 5.2","\n","Beta1: 4",....)
```

Is there any way to make that simple result format?

Comment: If you want Summary of Linear Regression Models as HTML Table, check out this package https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/sjtlm.html

Comment: Assuming beta values are stored in  list`l`,just `cat("Coefficients","\n","-------------\n",paste("Beta",1:length(l),": ",l,"\n"))`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vector of 10 results and you want to label them Beta1 to Beta10 you could do:

```
result = 10:1
b_order = 1:10

paste0("beta", b_order, ": ", result)
```

This gives:

```
[1] "beta1: 10" "beta2: 9"  "beta3: 8"  "beta4: 7"  "beta5: 6"  "beta6: 5"  "beta7: 4"  "beta8: 3"  "beta9: 2"  "beta10: 1"
```

Comment: Can also wrap in `cat` for multiline output per the OP's title, maybe `cat(sep="\n", paste0("beta", b_order, ": ", result))`